# How to right align the last LI in bootstrap 5 navbar

Tags: bootstrap-5

The examples on the Bootstrap 5 site only show non-LI nav items aligned to the right.

I have 4 menu items, 3 should be left aligned while the last should be pushed to the right.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with the classes `.me-auto` on the left div or `.ms-auto` on the right div. This adds a margin between the two different navigation elements. Here a short demo, but you can see some other examples with a searchbar in the [navbar-documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/).

Changed navbar-expand-lg to just navbar-expand so the example is easily visible without needing to go fullpage.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap navbar demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <!-- div class="navbar-nav"> -->
        <!-- use me-auto here... -->
        <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </div>
        <!-- ...or use ms-auto here -->
        <!-- <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto"> -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Account</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Logout</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that these changes would not have any visual effect on the mobile version of the navigation. Also, if you are using e.g. `div`s or lists (`ul`/`ol`) for the navigation will not make any visual difference with bootstrap. However, it could make an impact in SEO and accessability.